# Simple functions question

Tags: functions

If $f(x)=x+1/x$, then prove that $[f(x)]^3=f(x^3)+ 3f(1/x)$.

Ans. $f(x^3)= x^3+1/x^3$

$[f(x)]^3= (x+1/x)^3$

Using the identity of $(a+b)^3$, we have $[f(x)]^3= (x^3+1/x^3) + 3(x+1/x)$

$[f(x)]^3= f(x^3)+3f(x)$

I have understood the solution till now, but what I don't understand is how $f(x)$ becomes $f(1/x)$. The given solution says that $f(x)=f(1/x)$ because $f(x)=x+1/x$. I didn't understand this part. can somebody please explain?

Also, this is another question but what would the inverse function of $f(x)=x+1/x$ be?

Answer (score 1):

They are equal:

$$f(1/x)=(1/x)+\frac{1}{(1/x)}=\frac{1}{x}+x=f(x).$$

To find the inverse of $y=f(x)=x+1/x,$ swap $x$ and $y$, i.e. write $x=y+1/y$, and solve for $y$. Then set $y=g(x)$. You must check that $(f \circ g)(x)=(g \circ f)(x)=x$ to verify that the $g(x)$ you found is indeed the inverse. If this property holds, then set $g(x)=f^{-1}(x),$ and this is your inverse.

Comment: There is no inverse. The fact that $f(x)=f(\frac 1 x)$ shows that $f$ is not injective.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy They don't teach that in precalculus. See my answer's edit.